# .MPP files not visible in search result in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, office-365, search-results

We have multiple .MPP (Microsoft Project Management) files that are not visible in search result in SharePoint Online.

The display form for the items are visible in search result but not the actual documents. 
Even after multiple calls with Microsoft support were I have shared my monitor and asked them why it doesn't work, they haven't been able to answer me.

I have found a couple of hints online, that .MPP files wasn't fully supported back in SP2010/SP2013 but nothing concrete on how they work today. I can understand if SharePoint Online doesn't support opening the files in browser but they should get indexed and shown in search result at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project *.mpp files are not crawled in SPO. Consequently, you are seeing "the next best thing" according to SharePoint which is a link to the DispItem page that matches your search query.

[Default Crawled File Types in SharePoint Online](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/technical-reference/default-crawled-file-name-extensions-and-parsed-file-types)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Interesting that MS-support couldn't help me with this after more than 4 hours of troubleshooting. :)

Comment: Microsoft support doesn't know anything about search or how it works.